# merge/concatenate row-wise pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date/Time           P1      P2      P83     ON      OFF
2014-01-13 11:41                    path 83     
2014-01-13 11:41                                    offline
2014-03-26 14:37    path 1              
2014-03-26 14:37                                    offline
2014-03-26 14:37                    path 83     
2014-03-26 15:33    path 1              
2014-03-26 15:33                            online  
2014-04-25 5:44             path 2          
2014-04-25 5:44                                     offline
```

I would like to merge the rows that have the same index and fill in the columns. There will never be the case that one column has values for the same index, i.e. the column values do not crash. The desired output is a dataframe like this:

```
Date/Time           P1      P2      P3      ON      OFF
2014-01-13 11:41                    path 83         offline
2014-03-26 14:37    path 1          path 83         offline
2014-03-26 15:33    path 1                  online
2014-04-25 5:44             path 2                  offline
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Does a naive.... `df.groupby('Date/Time').first()` work for you?

Comment: I am surprised that I spent a day on this :)
It works fine. Any suggestions on how to merge the two last columns (ON and OFF) to one column?
If you would please write your answer as an "answer" so I could accept it?

Comment: Umm... maybe once you've done the grouping, then `df['STATUS'] = df['ON'].fillna(df['OFF'])` ?

Comment: Are you able to provide a more easily copy/pastable DF? Or include it as code or `df.to_dict()` or similar? Your example above is somewhat not great to parse to make it a usable DF to run things against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby the key and apply `.first()`

```
agg = df.groupby('Date/Time').first()
```

Create new column for "status":

```
agg['STATUS'] = agg['ON'].fillna(agg['OFF'])
```

Drop columns if needed:

```
agg.drop(['ON', 'OFF'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Leaves you `agg` as:

```
                      P1      P2      P83   STATUS
Date/Time                                         
2014-01-13 11:41     NaN     NaN  path 83  offline
2014-03-26 14:37  path 1     NaN  path 83  offline
2014-03-26 15:33  path 1     NaN      NaN   online
2014-04-25 5:44      NaN  path 2      NaN  offline
```